# Javascript all fields not getting validated

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my code of HTML, in it , it is validating for first two fields only i.e. Baby's Name and Mobile number only by popping window alert message when I  click on submit button, but don't know why it is not validating the below fields, and throw an error message while submitting the entry in database because the image etc. fields are null.   I tried a lot, but unable to find the mistake .

```
<script> 
function BabyContest()                                    
{ 
    var baby_name = document.forms["RegForm"]["baby_name"];               
    var mob_no = document.forms["RegForm"]["mob_no"];    
    var guardian_email = document.forms["RegForm"]["guardian_email"];  
    var dob =  document.forms["RegForm"]["dob"];  
    var lines_for_baby = document.forms["RegForm"]["lines_for_baby"];  
    var image_file =  document.forms["RegForm"]["image_file"];  
     
   
    if (baby_name.value == "")                                  
    { 
        window.alert("Please enter your baby's name."); 
        baby_name.focus(); 
        return false; 
    } 
   
 
    if (mob_no.value.match(/^\(?([6-9]{1})\)?([0-9]{9})$/))
        {
      return true;
        }
      else
        {
        alert("Please enter a Valid 10 digit Mobile Number");
        mob_no.focus();
        return false;
        }
           
    if (guardian_email.value == "")                                   
    { 
        window.alert("Please enter a email address."); 
        guardian_email.focus(); 
        return false; 
        }
        else
        {
          if (guardian_email.value != "")
          {
            if (guardian_email.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/))
            {
          return true;
            }
          else
            {
            alert("Please enter a Valid Email Address");
            guardian_email.focus()
            return false;
            }
          }
        }

   
    if (dob.value == "")                           
    { 
        window.alert("Please enter baby's date of birth."); 
        dob.focus(); 
        return false; 
    } 
   
    if (lines_for_baby.value == "")                        
    { 
        window.alert("Please write some lines for baby"); 
        lines_for_baby.focus(); 
        return false; 
    } 

    if (image_file.value == "")                        
    { 
        window.alert("Please input Image file"); 
        image_file.focus(); 
        return false; 
    } 
   
    return true; 
}
</script>
```

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="RegForm" onsubmit="return BabyContest()">
      <p class="title-font sm:text-xl text-xl mb-4 font-small text-blue-600"><b>Enter Baby's Name</b></p>
      <div class="flex w-full md:justify-start justify-center">
        <input class="bg-gray-100 rounded mr-4 border border-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 text-base px-4 lg:w-full xl:w-1/2 w-2/4" placeholder="Enter Contestant's Name" type="text" name="baby_name" >        
      </div>
      <p class="title-font sm:text-xl text-xl mb-4 font-small text-blue-600"><b> Guardian's Mobile No:</b></p>
      <div class="flex w-full md:justify-start justify-center">
        <input class="bg-gray-100 rounded mr-4 border border-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 text-base px-4 lg:w-full xl:w-1/2 w-2/4" placeholder="Enter 10 digit Mobile No." type="tel" name="mob_no" >        
      </div>
      <p class="title-font sm:text-xl text-xl mb-4 font-small text-blue-600"><b>Enter Guardian' email</b></p>
      <div class="flex w-full md:justify-start justify-center">
        <input class="bg-gray-100 rounded mr-4 border border-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 text-base px-4 lg:w-full xl:w-1/2 w-2/4" placeholder="Enter valid Email address" type="email" name="guardian_email" >        
      </div>
      <p class="text-sm mt-2 text-gray-500 mb-8 w-full">Please enter a valid email address as further communicaiton will be done this email</p>
      <p class="title-font sm:text-xl text-xl mb-4 font-small text-blue-600"><b>Date Of Birth Of Your Baby</b></p>
      <div class="flex w-full md:justify-start justify-center">
        <input class="bg-gray-100 rounded mr-4 border border-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 text-base px-4 lg:w-full xl:w-1/2 w-2/4" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" type="date" name="dob" >  
     
      </div>
      <p class="title-font sm:text-xl text-xl mb-4 font-small text-blue-600"><b>Some Pleasurable Lines For Baby</b></p>
      <div class="flex w-full md:justify-start justify-center">
        <textarea class="bg-gray-100 rounded mr-4 border border-gray-400 h-48 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 text-base px-4 lg:w-full xl:w-1/2 w-2/4" placeholder="Write some Pleasurable Lines For Baby" type="text" name="lines_for_baby" ></textarea>     
      </div>
      
      <p class="title-font sm:text-xl text-xl mb-4 font-small text-blue-600"><b>Please Upload Image Of Baby</b></p>
      <div class = "row">

            <input type="file" name="image_file"  >
            <button type="submit" class="inline-flex text-white bg-indigo-500 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded text-lg" >Submit </button>
          </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: If your question has been answered satisfactorily, please consider selecting an answer to mark so as to conclude your question.

Answer (score 0):

The mobile number check has a `return true` enclosed in its `if` statement which short-circuits the rest of the function.  You should have only one `return true` at the end of the function after every check has succeeded, i.e., has not applied `return false`.

For example, you might consider changing the mobile number check line to

`if (!mob_no.value.match(/^\(?([6-9]{1})\)?([0-9]{9})$/))`

and remove the `return true` section of that `if` statement entirely.

Another way to accomplish this in general is to have a variable `var ret = true` and set this variable in each check as appropriate, then `return ret` at the end.  This approach will have the side effect that the end-user will (possibly) receive multiple alerts, so the mechanism of `return false` at the first failure is more appropriate for this application.